# AcceptOnceFileFilter keeps other filters from working in a CompositeFileListFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have beat my head against the wall for quite some time on this issue and tested it multiple ways plus dug into the source code and cannot find out why it is not working.

I have the need for a composite filter so that I can filter and provide other industry standard polling checks. The code below is the core part of the issue and it is in an Inbound Channel Adapter.

The code works fine if addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter()) is not in the code. As soon as you put it in, no files are ever found. It will work if I take the RegexPatternFileListFilter out of the scenario.

```
CompositeFileListFilter<File> compositeFileListFilter= new CompositeFileListFilter<File>();
compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter(".*_CLAIM_.*[.]txt"));
compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(lastModifiedFilter());

FileReadingMessageSource pollDirectory = new FileReadingMessageSource();    
pollDirectory.setDirectory(new File(pollingDirectory)); 
pollDirectory.setAutoCreateDirectory(false);
pollDirectory.setFilter(compositeFileListFilter);
pollDirectory.setLocker(new NioFileLocker());
```

Update 09/21/2016:
An example Spring Boot application showing this issue has been uploaded to:
https://github.com/tedwards-rogue/AcceptOnceFileFilter-Test

Comment: Well, will it be difficult for you to come up with some Spring Boot application to play from our side? Or at least provide debug logs for Spring Integration category.

Comment: How can I bundle the code up directly to you guys at Pivotal? It is in a private Git repository at the moment.

Comment: If that is enough simple generic Spring Boot application, you can just make it as public. If your app is very big, we are not intended to dig so far. Although you can give my user permissions to see your private repo: https://github.com/artembilan

Comment: I see your code, thanks. But as I said: that is very big app and complicated. I don't have enough time to investigate all the domain. Since you claim the issue with the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` on the `FileReadingMessageSource`, just try to localize code and provide simple test.

Comment: I have created an application and tested it. Uploaded to GitHub.

Comment: Great! How about to share that with me ?

Comment: It is now a public GitHub repository. See update to original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, looks like I know where is problem.

Look into your code one more time:

```
CompositeFileListFilter<File> compositeFileListFilter= new CompositeFileListFilter<File>();
compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("(?i).*_CLAIM_.*[.]txt"));
compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(lastModifiedFilter());
compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter());
```

See, you are in trap because of wrong order of filters.

When you have `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` there in the middle, it accepts the file first time and stores it in the its cache to avoid this one for the next time.

Now we go to other filters in the chain and meet here `LastModifiedFileListFilter` with the `age == 15` seconds. Now its JavaDocs:

```
* The {@link FileListFilter} implementation to filter those files which
* {@link File#lastModified()} is less than the {@link #age} in comparison
* with the current time.
* <p>
* The resolution is done in seconds.
```

So, if file is young enough, we skip it. Eventually that file becomes old, but (!!!). Do you remember that we have `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` before? So, even if that file is ready for processing by the `LastModifiedFileListFilter`, we don't pass because it is filtered already by the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`.

So, the fix for your problem is to move `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` to the end of the chain.

**UPDATE**

Also be aware of `ChainFileListFilter` available since version `4.3.7`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-reading

Comment: I have confirmed that you are correct. I was wondering about order myself but could not find anything in the documentation or Java docs which would lead me to that conclusion. Maybe this is a specific edge case, but maybe a comment in the code for AcceptOnceFileListFilter would help. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, changing the order did not help and checking CompositeFileListFilter.filterFiles method shows that all files are sent to all filters

Comment: Would you mind starting a new SO question with more context and maybe some code to play from our side?